# Padding spaces to strings in a series with variable lenght

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to pad "_" on both side of string in a dataframe series.

Here is the dataframe.

```
A
cat
dog
rat
```

So i used this

```
A.str.pad(5, side='both', fillchar="_")
```

Output

```
A
_cat_
_dog_
_rat_
```

but now I got a series with variable length of string.

```
A
cat
dog
rat
crocodile
moose
```

expected output

```
A
_cat_
_dog_
_rat_
_crocodile_
_moose_
```

One way I can do is iterate through the entire dataframe, but I need a pandas way to do that. I am using pandas and python 3.

Comment: `'_' + A + '_'` ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic pandas operations will give you what you want

```
'_' + df['A'].astype(str) + '_'
```

Output:

```
0          _cat_
1          _dog_
2          _rat_
3    _crocodile_
4        _moose_
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version, using `apply` and modern (Python >= 3.6) string formatting

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['A', 'cat', 'dog', 'rat', 'crocodile', 'moose'])
print(s)
s = s.apply(lambda x: f'_{x}_',)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
0            A
1          cat
2          dog
3          rat
4    crocodile
5        moose
dtype: object
0            _A_
1          _cat_
2          _dog_
3          _rat_
4    _crocodile_
5        _moose_
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use apply:

```
s = pd.Series(['A', 'cat', 'dog', 'rat', 'crocodile', 'moose'])
s.apply(lambda x: "_" + x + "_")
```